# Fastest way to convert a binary list(or array) into an integer in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

Suppose there is a list(or an array) which contains 1s and 0s.

```
gona = [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1]
```

I want to convert this into the integer represented by the binary value `100011` (The number made out of the elements in the list).

I know that this can be done as follows.

```
int("".join(map(str, gona)),2)
```

or

edit:    `int("".join([str(i) for i in gona]),2)`

Is there any other faster way to do this?

Comment: faster as in *less code*, or in *less CPU time*?

Comment: @goncalopp, in less CPU time. In fact I would have mentioned if I want that in less code. "Fast" means with greater speed.

Comment: If you down vote this question, please provide a reasonable reason as well.

Comment: Your second option doesn't even work for me.  I get a TypeError, expected string, int found.

Comment: `[str(i) for i in gona]`, perhaps

Comment: @Sohcahtoa82 That works and it's also the fastest. You probably miscopied it.

Comment: Is the typical list small as in this example, or large? That can significantly change the optimal code.

Comment: In my case the length of the list would be exactly 32 or less.

Comment: I triple-checked it.  As written, it doesn't work unless I use the change that @Ben posted.  EDIT: Nevermind.  I was commenting before the question was edited.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the fastest I came up with. A slight variation of your initial solution:

```
digits = ['0', '1']
int("".join([ digits[y] for y in x ]), 2)

%timeit int("".join([digits[y] for y in x]),2)
100000 loops, best of 3: 6.15 us per loop
%timeit int("".join(map(str, x)),2)
100000 loops, best of 3: 7.49 us per loop
```

(Btw, it seems that in this case, using a list comprehension is faster than using a generator expression.)

EDIT:

Also, I hate being a smartass, but you can always trade memory for speed:

```
# one time precalculation
cache_N = 16  # or much bigger?!
cache = {
   tuple(x): int("".join([digits[y] for y in x]),2)
   for x in itertools.product((0,1), repeat=cache_N)
}
```

Then:

```
res = cache[tuple(x)]
```

Way faster. Of course, this is only feasible up to a point...

EDIT2:

I now see you say your lists have 32 elements. In this case the caching solution is probably infeasible, BUT we have more ways to trade speed for memory. E.g., with `cache_N=16`, which is surely feasible, you can access it twice:

```
c = 2 ** cache_N # compute once
xx = tuple(x)
cache[xx[:16]] * c + cache[xx[16:]]

%timeit cache[xx[:16]] * c + cache[xx[16:]]
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.23 us per loop  # YES!
```

Comment: Yes, in case of [`str.join` LC is always faster than a genexp](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9061024/846892). +1 Nice trick to save some function call's nanoseconds by using indexing.

Comment: This is the fastest version up to now.

Comment: Well this is quite amazing. This is about 10 times faster than other methods. I think I should accept this as the answer at the moment. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You could do it like this:

```
sum(x << i for i, x in enumerate(reversed(gona)))
```

Although it's not much faster

Comment: in fact, according to `timeit` on Python 2.7 on my machine, it's even a bit slower

Comment: This is going to be really slow for bigger lists.

Answer (score 2):

I decided to create a script to trial 4 different methods of doing this task.

```
import time

trials = range(1000000)
list1 = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0]
list0 = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
listmix = [1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0]

def test1(l):
    start = time.time()
    for trial in trials:
        tot = 0
        n = 1
    for i in reversed(l):
            if i:
                tot += 2**n
            n += 1
    print 'Time taken:', str(time.time() - start)

def test2(l):
    start = time.time()
    for trial in trials:
        int("".join(map(str, l)),2)
    print 'Time taken:', str(time.time() - start)

def test3(l):
    start = time.time()
    for trial in trials:
        sum(x << i for i, x in enumerate(reversed(l)))
    print 'Time taken:', str(time.time() - start)

def test4(l):
    start = time.time()
    for trial in trials:
        int("".join([str(i) for i in l]),2)
    print 'Time taken:', str(time.time() - start)


test1(list1)
test2(list1)
test3(list1)
test4(list1)
print '.'
test1(list0)
test2(list0)
test3(list0)
test4(list0)
print '.'
test1(listmix)
test2(listmix)
test3(listmix)
test4(listmix)
```

My results:

```
Time taken: 7.14670491219
Time taken: 5.4076821804
Time taken: 4.7349550724
Time taken: 7.24234819412
.
Time taken: 2.29213285446
Time taken: 5.38784003258
Time taken: 4.70707392693
Time taken: 7.27936697006
.
Time taken: 4.78960323334
Time taken: 5.36612486839
Time taken: 4.70103287697
Time taken: 7.22436404228
```

Conclusion: @goncalopp's solution is probably the best one.  It is consistently fast.  On the other hand, if you're likely to have more zeros than ones, stepping through the list and manually multiplying powers of two and adding them will be fastest.

EDIT: I re-wrote my script to use timeit, the source code is at http://pastebin.com/m6sSmmR6

My output result:

```
7.78366303444
2.79321694374
5.29976511002
.
5.72017598152
5.70349907875
5.66881299019
.
5.25683712959
5.17318511009
5.20052909851
.
8.23388290405
8.24193501472
8.15649604797
.
3.94102287292
3.95323395729
3.9201271534
```

My method of stepping through the list backwards adding powers of two is still faster if you have all zeros, but otherwise, @sxh2's method is definitely the fastest, and my implementation didn't even include his caching optimization.

Comment: If you want to time short code snippets, [`timeit`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html) is generally better than doing it by hand.

Comment: Change length of your lists to 1000 and time again, and use timeit module as @user2357112 said.

Comment: Actually I got your first method way faster than other methods.

Comment: Ah! I missed OP's comment related to list's length.

Comment: @user2357112: I tend to forget about timeit.  I'm rewriting it with timeit and I'll post new results.

Comment: I think in your first test, `n` should be initialized to `0`. Otherwise it will double the result.

Comment: @maheshakya: You are correct.  I'll have new test results in a minute.

Answer (score 1):

I tried this:

```
int(str(gona).replace(', ','')[1:-1])
```

and compared to this (which was @Sohcahtoa82 fastest case):

```
sum(x << i for i, x in enumerate(reversed(gona)))
```

On my machine, the first does 1000000 passes in ~5.97s. The second case takes ~8.03s.

I tried another approach, and inserted into @Sohcahtoa82's code:

```
T61 = """
    l = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
    digits = ['0', '1']
    s = ''
    for y in l:
        s += digits[y]
    int(s, 2)
"""

T60 = """
    l = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
    digits = ['0', '1']
    s = ''
    for y in l:
        s += digits[y]
    int(s, 2)
"""

T6mix = """
    l = [1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0]
    digits = ['0', '1']
    s = ''
    for y in l:
        s += digits[y]
    int(s, 2)
"""
```

And got these results. Mine is the last set of times.

```
5.45334255339
1.89000112578
4.14859673729
.
4.39018410496
4.21122597336
4.57919181895
.
3.59095765307
3.25353409619
3.78588067833
.
6.53343932548
6.33234985363
6.65685678006
.
2.74509861151
2.6111819044
2.83928911064
.
2.79519545737
2.66091503704
2.9183024407
```